# Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no '...' member

Tags: python, database, web, flask

I'm creating a database following this guide https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database, but I have an issue.
I've already installed the `sql-alchemy` in the `venv` of my project, but vs-code shows me this problem.

```
app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models

--------------------------------
app/models.py

from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True,unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True,unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

issue:
 [image: image of error messages]

Comment: Please post your code by copy-pasting it and not as an image.

Comment: put text instead of images

Comment: done, i've edited the message

Answer (score 1):

> I've already installed the sql-alchemy in the venv of my project

You installed sql-alchemy. The tutorial says to install flask-sqlalchemy.

```
(venv) $ pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

flask-sqlalchemy makes it easier to work with flask and sql-alchemy. It's easy to get it mixed up with just sql-alchemy which is its own module.